# DataGrid alike Outlook in WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, datagridview, wpf-controls

I want to design a DataGrid in which I have option to "Group by" or "Arrange by" filtering, just like we have in outlook. In outlook or windows explorer we have option to change the view in accordance with what is selected in Group By option.
I am wondering if any one have any idea of this type of implementation or any open source in WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [WPF toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/29117). They have a data grid that supports things like this. It's open source so you should be able to take a look at their implementation.

[Codeplex WPF project page](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf)